# MVC 3 and Google Contacts API

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, contacts

I am trying to delete contacts from my application and also from a users Google Mail contacts, which I am using a helper file for. The helper file has the following Delete method:

```
public static void Delete(string pGoogleUsername, string pGooglePassword, string EditUri)
    {
        RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings("myApplication", pGoogleUsername, pGooglePassword);
        rs.AutoPaging = true;
        ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs);

        ***ContactsQuery query = new ContactsQuery();
        query.Uri = new Uri(EditUri);

        AtomFeed contacts = rs.Query(query);

        AtomEntry entry = new AtomEntry();
        entry = contacts.Entries[0];***

        entry.Delete();
    }
```

I feel okay about the code, apart from the code inside the stars. I get an error under the word "Query" in AtomFeed contacts = rs.Query(query);.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See if my code here helps you get your contacts a bit better:

[MVC 3 and Google Contacts API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860749/mvc-3-and-google-contacts-api/5860900#5860900)

try for instance: `cr.Delete(entry);` or `f.Entries.First()` etc inside the following loop:

```
foreach (Contact entry in f.Entries)
```